# FlexMonkey Issue with TitleWindow Popups

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-monkey

We are currently testing parts of our application that open in popup windows. These windows are subclasses of TitleWindow. The issue we now run into is that the popups seems to be registered multiple times and that tests are sometimes executed on popups that have already been closed (or so it seems).

I thought this had to do with the way we closed and removed our popups, but I can't really spot any problems there. After looking into the FlexMonkey source code, I saw that there is an explicit check for "TitleWindow" in the ADDED_TO_STAGE handler, after which the popup is added as an application window. But the popup never seems to be removed from the "_windows" collection. As a result, when you open the tree view in FlexMonkey, there are several instances of the same popup window class. This probably also explains why our tests sometimes do not seem to run (visually), but execute and verify correctly, as they are ran on a hidden instance of a popup. I would expect the MonkeyAutomationManager to also listen to REMOVED_FROM_STAGE events and remove the popup when it is closed.

Am I missing something here or is this an (known) issue?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it isn't an issue, it's simply that your code isn't properly cleaning the object and removing it from the display list.  You also need to remember that garbage collection does not run right after you remove something from the stage.  It could be possible that your window, even if it has been removed from the stage is in fact still listening and responding to events.